# Elliptic Curve Cryptography Shared Secret Key Derivation

Tags: java, flutter, encryption, ecdh

I am implementing ECDH and wanted to ask how the shared secret that is derived from one's private key and another's public key should be best used.

I got the fact that both parties using this end up with the same secret, which is fine. The secret gets compromised once an attacker gets hold of a private key of any of the two parties involved in a communication (Alice or Bob).

It appears that the (shared) secret is always the same when calculating the key agreement using a certain algorithm (in my case AES).

Then you use the secret and use AES/GCM to encrypt whatever one wants.

I think that this is flawed as you always use the same key for communication between the same partner making it possible to record the secret communication and there might be a chance to derive the secret by just cracking AES or whatever is used.

So what I want to do is deriving keys from it instead without ever using the entire secure key as is. So instead of using the secret key both are able to generate independently, I would like to use the secret key to derive a number of keys passing along kind of an offset both sides use to create unlimited one time keys.

My question is what Key Derivation function is usually used (as it is key based)?

I currently implemented a SipHash128 as it promises what I need - keeping the actual secret secret but allow for infinite symmetric secrets by exchanging random numbers as messages (one part from the device and one part from the server) to derive the sip hash from by using the shared secret key avoiding the device being able to always send the same 'random' messages.

PS: I want a Java Backend talking to Flutter and JavaScript apps.
PSS: Yes I have a Master (a colleague challenged me on this already) in Computer Science but feel kind of stupid doing it this way, but it was/is the easiest solution I could come up with.

Comment: What you use the static-static ECDH and you should avoid it since doesn't provide perfect forward secrecy. to use ephemeral-ephemeral you need to generate a new public-private key for each key agreement. Then the problem is the validation of the new keys against the middle attack. To mitigate, use signatures for the new keys. This is what similar to TLS does.

Comment: You are right. I use it for device identification by storing the device's public key in the database and use this as a challenge for the device to authenticate itself. For the secret used to communicate I currently settled with a sip hash based on the secret key and will update the post accordingly. If someone can access the device, I don't actually care since you can always get the information from local storage or jail-break it and do stuff on the OS level.

Comment: Libsodium handles this: https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/public-key_cryptography/authenticated_encryption and https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/bindings_for_other_languages

Comment: *"I use it for device identification by storing the device's public key in the database and use this as a challenge for the device to authenticate itself."* I hope you're not using ECDH for that, because this is not its purpose. Use EdDSA or similar for that.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I use it for that. I need secure communication over unsecure medium and verifying authentication is a freebe that comes along with it. But you are right regarding Ed25519 and similar. For only authentication this is simpler and better.